# Fans kick in very late after ssd upgrade

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, cpu, temperature, gpu

Recently I replaced my MBP Mid-2010 HDD with a Zotac 480G Premium SSD. Things are really faster now, but one thing I noticed is that the CPU rises to peaks quite unprecedented with my original HDD. In video conversion, the CPU temperature soars to 95 degrees Celsius but the fans seem sluggish to kick in before the CPU temperature is 85 or so. The GPU temperature is also quite high. Of course, after they start spinning up they both work around 6000, but they cannot lower the CPU temperature below 92 degrees Celsius. I have stared to think of putting the HDD back. In idle mode while I am not working with my mac, the CPU temp is around 49, but on startup and when working with apps like pages the temperature is around 66 degrees.

What do think? When do your fans usually kick in while you are having a cpu-intensive process running in your mac?

Update: Here are two images related to CPU usage and temperature. I hope it helps.

[image: CPU Usage on Video Conversion]
[image: Temperature]

Regards

Comment: Fans will be on if CPU is at full speed. Lools like your hard disk was too slow to provide enough data to the CPU for it to run at full speed

Comment: When doing a video conversion, the cpu runs at about 300%. So the right amount of data is provided for it, I suppose.

Comment: Even that is slow - as CPUs are 4 core (or possibly 8 core) so good use of the CPU should be nearer 400%

Comment: Mine is 2 cores. It is a core i5. But it sure is faster than an HDD in providing the CPU with ample amount of required data, don't you think? I never had this problem with the HDD, though.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a problem that your CPU is at 95 degrees celcicus for a short period of time.

The mid-2010 MacBook Pro with Core i5 processor is specified to withstand up to 105 degrees.

So unless you have some kind of practical problem (for example the underside of the laptop being too hot to handle), there's really nothing to worry about.

Comment: Hi jksoegaard. Thanks for your reply. Actually, I already knew that, but why didn't I have that problem before with my previous HDD drive? The temperature never rose to over 80 degrees Celsius then, but now my computer has to get used to temperatures around 90 or even 100 degrees.